# Uncaugth reference error custom event not defind in the file ratchet

Tags: javascript, cordova, ratchet, push.js

Hai i am new in phonegap and ratchet framework.I am trying to load external script with push.js. Here is my js file contents

```
function init(){
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady(){

        alert("device ready for use");
        }
       var checkPage = function(){

        alert("push");
        var scriptName; 
        var scriptsList = document.querySelectorAll('script.js-custom');  // Add a "js-custom" class to your script tag
        for (var i = 0; i<scriptsList.length;i++) {

            // Handle scripts in separate files by assigning the script file name to its id.
            // We save it in a variable because the ".done" callback is asynchronous.
            scriptName = scriptsList[i].id;  // IMPORTANT: Only one loadable script per page!
            $.getScript("js/" + scriptName)
              .done(function (script, textStatus) {
                  eval(script);
                  alert("ok");
              })
              .fail(function(){
                  alert("error");
              });

        }


    };   

    window.addEventListener('push', checkPage);

    }
```

Here is my html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">  
    <title>Ratchet template page</title>

    <!-- Sets initial viewport load and disables zooming  -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">

    <!-- Makes your prototype chrome-less once bookmarked to your phone's home screen -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">

    <!-- Include the compiled Ratchet CSS -->
    <link href="css/ratchet.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Include the compiled Ratchet JS -->
    <script src="js/ratchet.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
     <script src="cordova.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body onload="init()">  

    <!-- Make sure all your bars are the first things in your <body> -->
    <header class="bar bar-nav">
      <h1 class="title">Ratchet</h1>
    </header>

    <!-- Wrap all non-bar HTML in the .content div (this is actually what scrolls) -->
    <div class="content">

      <div class="card">
        <ul class="table-view">
          <li class="table-view-cell">

            <a class="push-right" href="two.html">
              <strong>Another page</strong>
            </a>
          </li>  
          <li class="table-view-cell"> 
            <a class="push-right" href="https://github.com/twbs/ratchet/">
              <strong>Ratchet on Github</strong>
            </a>

      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my two.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Notes</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">

    <!-- Roboto
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700"> -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ratchet.min.css">
    <script src="ratchet.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <header class="bar bar-nav">
  <h1 class="title">Two</h1>
    </header>
  </body>
  <div class="content">
  <script src="js/sample.js" class="js-custom" id="sample.js"></script>
  </div>
</html>
```

But i run the project i  get

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: CustomEvent is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/js/ratchet.min.js:10
```

please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have cordova in your second html file. When you load two.html, your browser destroys the previous page and all the scripts associated with it. You should do everything in single page, I suggest using an mvvm framework such as angularjs, emberjs etc.

So, to be exact, your second html does not have cordova, so deviceready is never fired for that file. However, for the first html, you have deviceready and ratchet references. But, in there, you don't have your sample.js reference with js-custom. So, inside deviceready (when in first html), your ratchet is complaining about missing js-custom reference.

Comment: But i loaded in device some times works correctly, sometimes not

Comment: add cordova first. then ratchet

Comment: please read my answer, I updated and pointed out the exact problem in your code (I suppose).

Comment: works fine with data-ignore="push", But i need push along with custom script

Comment: Can you give an answer for this? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25831459/pushnotifcation-in-phongap-android-multiple-registrion-ids-of-the-same-device)

Answer (score 8):

It's because window.CustomEvent is missing in you WebView implementation.

Add this Polyfill and it works every times. I found the solution on Mozilla Developer Network:

```
/*
 * Polyfill for adding CustomEvent
 * see : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent
 */

if (!window.CustomEvent) { // Create only if it doesn't exist
    (function () {
        function CustomEvent ( event, params ) {
            params = params || { bubbles: false, cancelable: false, detail: undefined };
            var evt = document.createEvent( 'CustomEvent' );
            evt.initCustomEvent( event, params.bubbles, params.cancelable, params.detail );
            return evt;
        };

        CustomEvent.prototype = window.Event.prototype;

        window.CustomEvent = CustomEvent;
    })();
}
```